# xamarin android webservice get error

Tags: xamarin

I am using the below code to create php mys1l webservice, when run app I get exception error, the server returns error 404 and the debugger points to this line:

```
var response = client.UploadValues(uri, parameters);
```

My complete code

```
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            Uri uri = new Uri("http://149.255.62.48/Login/xamarinsignIn.php");


            NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
            parameters.Add("uemail", userEmail);
            parameters.Add("pass", userPassword);
            var response = client.UploadValues(uri, parameters);
            var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
            JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(responseString);
            if (ob.OptString("success").Equals("1"))
            {


                mainActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                Toast.MakeText(mainActivity, "You Successfully LogIn", ToastLength.Short).Show());
            }
            else {
                mainActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                                           Toast.MakeText(mainActivity, "InValid Email or Password", ToastLength.Short).Show());

            }
```

Comment: I suggest that you manually verify the operation of that URL using an http utility such as Postman.

Comment: You are passing user credentials over the internet you should be using https

Comment: thank you for respond, I change to https but I get error (warning error trustfailure the authentication or decryption has failed)